# Work with nested task

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have `Client` and `Server` classes.

The `Server` return a `ResultWithNestedTask` instance.

```
public class ResultWithNestedTask
{
    public Task<String> NestedTask;
    public string Result;
}
```

The `Client` displays the data from `Result`, then waits for the completion of `NestedTask` and displays the result from `NestedTask`.

The `Server`:

1. Starts a new `Task` and waits for the result
2. Starts a nested task and returns the task to the client
3. Waits for the nested task to complete before doing some work with result.

Server's method `DoWorkAsync`:

```
    static async Task<ResultWithNestedTask> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        // start new Task and wait result
        var resultTask = await Task<String>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {                
            return "Result task.";
        });

        //start neasted task 
        var resultNestedTask = Task<String>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait(); //wait while return data 
            return "Result neasted task.";
        });

        //do some work whith nested task
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                resultNestedTask.Wait();
                var resultFromNestedTask = resultNestedTask.Result;
                resultFromNestedTask = "Updated string";
                Console.WriteLine(resultFromNestedTask);
            });

        //return result string and neasted task to the client
        return new ResultWithNestedTask()
        {
            NestedTask = resultNestedTask,
            Result = resultTask,
        };
    }
```

Client:

```
var taskResult = await DoWorkAsync();

// writeline result string
Console.WriteLine(taskResult.Result);

// client wait NestedTask
var nestedTask = await taskResult.NestedTask;

// writeline result string from nested task
Console.WriteLine(nestedTask);
```

This code should not block the UI.

The server returns the nested task and doesn't wait for the nested task to finish.

```
 //do some work with the nested task
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
     resultNestedTask.Wait();
     var resultFromNestedTask = resultNestedTask.Result;
     resultFromNestedTask = "Updated string";
     Console.WriteLine(resultFromNestedTask);
 });
```

I want to return the result before the task completes.

Client and Server are abstractions, and just one class takes data from another class.

Is this normal code? Do you see any problems?

Comment: I find it hard to review this code, because it's obviously example code. Code you post to CR should be *real code*.

Comment: Maybe better suited for the [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) site?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Task<string>.Factory.StartNew` you can do `Task.Factory.StartNew`.
However, instead of using `Task.Factory.StartNew` you can use `Task.Run`. It is simpler and supports more advanced scenarios. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506141347/https://web.archive.org/web/20160720084501/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).